# ClassNotFoundException when app launch

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, launching-application

I created an Andriod app for a Chinese Newspaper Company.

From the Exception/ANR report of Google Play Store, it was found that some users encountered the problem of ClassNotFoundException when they launch the app.
The app cannot found the activity marked as

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

The frequency is about every 3 sessions out of 500000.
What are the possibilities leading to ClassNotFoundException?

Remakrs:
 I doubt if this related to the package name.
In the first few lines of AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.abc.news"
```

the source code are stored in different folder name (Real file storage place)

```
com.anotherCompany.abc
```

so.. in the activity tag (AndroidManifest)

```
<activity
   android:name="com.anotherCompany.abc.MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens rarely, I think you shouldn't worry too much about it.

It can be due to a bad installation, a bad phone backup, or some android mods. But probably not something related to your code.